# Issue on magento installation in xampp localhost

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I install magento on xampp localhost first time, the error occurred when i enter the DB details and click on continue, the error is:

```
There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 798243806
```

I checked in the phpmyadmin, there are 85 tables created in magento DB.

I also check in php.ini these lines

```
extension=php_mcrypt.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_pdo.dll
```

They are also un commented in php.ini

**Edit:** I also check this file var\report\798243806 here is the written that i don't understand

```
a:5:{i:0;s:210:"Error in file: "D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\sql\catalog_setup\install-1.6.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'catalog_product_entity' already exists";i:1;s:950:"#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.6.0.0.19')
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.6.0.0.19')
#3 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:9:"/magento/";s:11:"script_name";s:18:"/magento/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

I don't know what is the issue. Please help me

Or any other tutorial for installation.

Comment: check in /var/report folder in your magento. There will be file with name 798243806 and check what is the issue

Comment: I think you need to rename your local.xml.sample file to local.xml.

Comment: @TBI See now my Edit question

Comment: @hardiksolanki where is this file located

Comment: you have to use fresh database for magento installation. i think you are using which is already in use. Create new database and use that name while installation of magento

Comment: please check this url : http://support.hostgator.in/articles/specialized-help/technical/magento-install-error-exception-printing-is-disabled

Comment: Thanx alot @TBI I install magento with new DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error clearly states:

> Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'catalog_product_entity'
>   already exists"

The install process is trying to create a table that is already created in the database.

What you need to do is to drop the database underlying database and create a new one for your install so that all tables are removed.